# How to skip missions in Dishonored?

Tags: dishonored, cheats

I played Dishonored a few years ago and got quite far in the game, but then stopped playing, moved to another computer, and I don't have the save files anymore.

Is there a way to skip missions in Dishonored, but so that the statistics, required items, and such necessary things get updated to some normal level?

Answer (score 2):

From my own experience, when I played on PC, you could not skip missions unless you already played that mission and completed it beforehand. Even if that happened, you can't skip a mission ingame, you can just skip to that section, so you don't have to play what happened beforehand. I am not aware of any cheats that could help what you wish for.